# Heroku PostgreSQL - Erro Status 500 na segunda consulta

Tags: postgresql, rest, heroku

Criei uma API REST em Node que faz requisições num PostgreSQL no Heroku. Uso o Postman para testar as requisições. Tá funcionando ok na primeira requisição (Status: 200).
Segue log do Heroku:

[image: Primeira consulta GET]

Mas quando tento fazer pela segunda vez, retorna erro (Status: 500 Internal Server Error).
Segue log do Heroku:

[image: Segunda consulta GET]

Um detalhe é que se espero um tempo, consigo efetuar uma consulta novamente. Mas a segunda continua dando o mesmo erro. Usei o Nodemon para testar a API no localhost. Coloquei as mesmas variáveis de ambiente do banco no Heroku pra ver se o erro acontecia. Deu a mesma coisa. A primeira status 200 e a segunda 500. Mas, talvez possa ser uma pista do problema, quando eu paro e reinicio o servidor com npm start, consigo fazer mais uma consulta.

Já procurei aqui nos tópicos e na internet e não consegui resolver. Não sei se o problema é tempo limite de uma conexão pra outra, se é com o Postgres ou com o plano gratuito do Heroku. Apreciaria muito se alguém tivesse uma luz para me ajudar. Segue meu código também:

[image: Método GET]

Comment: Para restringir a origem do problema rode suas consultas diretamente no PostgreSQL e verifique se ocorre algum erro. Se não apresentar erro então o problema não é no PostgreSQL. Vá eliminando cada uma das coisas que usa até identificar aonde ocorre o problema. De qualquer maneira posso adiantar que o PostgreSQL não possui erro 500.

Comment: Já havia testado no PostgreSQL. Funciona normalmente para quantas query eu fizer. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Mas no Postman continua o mesmo problema.